# Visitor stability vs instanceof flexibility

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I am working on a GUI application which generates a configuration file. I have a class hierarchy for the configuration model and I use an object tree of that hierarchy in several different contexts. Currently, I use the Visitor pattern to avoid polluting my model classes with context specific code.

```
interface IConfigurationElement {
    void acceptVisitor(IConfigurationElementVisitor visitor);
}
```

In an earlier version I used chains of `instanceof` conditions instead of the Visitor. Comparing the two approaches I see the following tradeofs.

*Visitor*

- It is easier and safer to add new `IConfigurationElement`. Just add a new declaration to `IConfigurationElementVisitor` and the compiler generates errors for all visitor implementations. With `instanceof` chains you have to remember all the places you have to extend with the new configuration element. Basically `instanceof` violates the DRY principle as it duplicates logic in several places.
- The visitor pattern is [more efficient](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.VisitorVersusInstanceOf) than a chain of `instanceof`conditions

*instanceof*

- The great advantage of `instanceof` is its flexibility. For example `instanceof`  allows me to define special solutions for different subsets of `IConfigurationElement` implementations which need to be handled similarilly in some cases. In contrast, Visitor forces me to implement a method for each implementation class every time.

Is there a common solution for this kind of problem? Can I adapt the Visitor somehow, so I can provide a common solution for some cases?

Comment: I would highly recommend you this blog tutorial which compares the different visitor style (instanceOf etc) and provides very interesting answers, it helped me I hope it woks for you too: http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/structural-pattern-matching-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

You could use visitor with instanceOf

interfaces:

```
interface Visitable {
  void accept(Object visitor);
}
interface AVisitor {
  void visitA(A a);
}
interface BVisitor {
  void visitB(B b);
}
interface CVisitor {
  void visitB(C c);
}
```

Visitables:

```
class C implements Visitable {
  public void accept(Object visitor) {
    if (visitor instanceof CVisitor) {
      ((BVisitor)vistor).visitC(this);
    }
  }
}

class B implements Visitable {
  public void accept(Object visitor) {
    if (visitor instanceof BVisitor) {
      ((BVisitor)vistor).visitB(this);
    }
  }
}

class A extends B implements Visitable {
  public void accept(Object visitor) {
    super.accept(visitor);
    if (visitor instanceof AVisitor) {
      ((AVisitor)vistor).visitA(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Visitors:

```
class PrintBs implements BVisitor {
  public void visitB(B b) {
    system.out.println(b);
  }
}

class PrintAs implements AVisitor {
  public void visitA(A a) {
    system.out.println(a);
  }
}

class PrintCs implements CVisitor {
  public void visitC(C c) {
    system.out.println(c);
  }
}
class PrintAsAndCs implements CVisitor, AVisitor{
  public void visitA(A a) {
    system.out.println(a);
  }
  public void visitC(C c) {
    system.out.println(c);
  }
}
```

each class knows only about its related interfaces, so adding new vistors nor visitables requires changing everything in that category (visitor/visitable) (for visitor, it does not require changing anything, for visitable it requires creating new visitor interface, but again, no changing of existing objects).

This way, there is no chain of instanceof tests and visitor for subset does not need to even know about types outside this subset.

Question is what to do with situation where A extends B (and B is Visitable too), in that case, you could just add super.accept(visitor) into accept (thus it would be short chain of instanceof-s, but onlu as long as hierarchy is deep, and it should not be too deep to matter, abd you don't need to write it whole manually).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you propose to remove `IConfigurationElementVisitor` and just check for specific visitor types in `Visitable`. While this is a possible solution I see some drawbacks. First this would remove the stability of Visitor I talked about and second I would pull knowledge about visitors into my `Visitable` implementations, which to avoid was part of the reason to use Visitor in the first place.

Comment: Not in Visitable (that should be only simple interface vith accept(Object visitor) ), but in implementations of Visitable. So each Class checks only for its visitor, so it knows only about fact that there exists interface for visiting it. I will modify my answer to make this clear.

Comment: Ok, your approach allows to have visitors which visit only specific subtypes of my structure. This is a nice idea. What i want is a little different (I should probably update my description). I want a compile time guarantee that all elements of my structure where visited but at the same time i want to treat some elements equally and some different. It is like @AndreasScheinert put it. Basically I want pattern matching with a compiler warning if the match is not exhaustive (like Scala's match with case classes).

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, you could. Capture the commonalities of the many configuration elements by assigning roles to them. You may end up with instanceof, but not in a way that violates the DRY principle, but rather as a way around Java's static typing.

```
class ConfigurationElementA implements IConfigurationElement, ICommittable {
}

class ConfigurationElementB implements IConfigurationElement, IVerifiable {
}

class Visitor {
    void accept(IConfigurationElement element) {
        if (element instanceof ICommittable) {
            // ...
        }

        // Note: not a chain of instanceofs.

        if (element instanceof IVerifiable) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, you let the visitor accept configuration elements generically, and act on groups of implementations via roles. Note that you can go as specific as you need by modeling your configuration elements accordingly.

You may recognize here Martin Fowler's [RoleInterface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html) pattern.

Comment: You basically use interfaces to define subsets of `IConfigurationElement` which can be handled specifically based on set membership. Unfortunately, as soon as you distinguish objects with `instanceof` your compiler won't be able to help you if you forget to update one of your visitors. Your solution has the benefit that all `instanceof` operators are embedded in a common type, which helps finding them by searching for the type.

Comment: My proposal comes from two observations about your use case: Firstly, you want to avoid a proliferation of `accept` method signatures. For this, I suggested a catch all approach, one that you can adapt to suit your needs, going more or less specific around your `IConfigurationElement` implementation. Second, you wanted the flexibility of instanceof, *presumably* (by the first case) because you have common traits in your implementation classes - otherwise, no reason to avoid `accept` proliferation to begin with. That's where I suggested `RoleInterface` which uses `instanceof` differently.

Comment: (You can still avoid `instanceof`: Make `IConfigurationElement` implement `IRoleEnabled` and have the visitor visit each configuration element as a role enabled item calling `visitRoleEnabled`, and having `visitRoleEnabled` in each implementation class call back into the visitor for each of the implemented roles. But with this we're starting to go wild on `instanceof` when it's really doing just fine.)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of some potential solutions:

1. create a private method in the `Visitor` implementation, and have multiple `visit` methods in the `Visitor` implementation call that private method.
2. if the above is repeated in many places, you can consider creating an abstract class that implements `Visitor`, and redirects a subset of `visit` implementations to a common `protected abstract` method.
3. create multiple `Visitor` interfaces:

   ```
   interface AOrB extends IConfigurationElementVisitor {
       <Result> Result accept(AOrBVisitor<Result> visitor);

       interface AOrBVisitor<Result> {
           Result visit(A a);
           Result visit(B b);
       }
   }

   interface ThisCouldBeOfTypeB extends IConfigurationElementVisitor {
       <Result> Result accept(ThisCouldBeOfTypeBVisitor<Result> visitor);

       interface ThisCouldBeOfTypeBVisitor<Result> {
           Result visit(B b);
           Result visit(ThisCouldBeOfTypeB visitable);
       }
   }

   class A implements AOrB, ThisCouldBeOfTypeB {...}

   class B implements AOrB, ThisCouldBeOfTypeB {...}

   class C implements ThisCouldBeOfTypeB {...}
   ```

I think 3 is what you are looking for. it is 100% static polymorphism, and generates compiler warnings if a type isn't handled. But the only disadvantage I can think of 3 is that maintaining the `Visitable*` implementations could become complex if there are a lot of different `Visitable*` interfaces.